# Error concatenating strings

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am trying to create a deck of cards. Early in my code I have the following.

```
suits = {"c","d","h","s"}
```

And I try to create the cards as follows

```
cardDeck = {};
for i=0, 3 do
   for j=1, 13 do
      local newCard = suits[i]..j;
   end
end
```

I get the following error: `Attempt to concatenate field '?' (a nil value)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your indexing should begin with 1, not 0. (I know it's counter-intuitive, but that's how Lua does it)

This code will do achieve what you want:

```
for i=1, 4 do
    for j=1, 13 do
        local newCard = suits[i]..j;
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks now I get new error. cardDeck.insert(cardDeck,tempCard) something about nil again. Attempt to call field 'insert' (a nil value).